# Get differences between two columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to compare two columns in Excel and get the list of elements that are present in the first column, but not the second one. The same elements are not in the same rows. My table looks like this:

[image: Sample data]

The expected output would be records "aadapa" and "acaso", since these are only two elements not present in the second column. "aklepac" and "apniewsk" are in the second column only, so shouldn't be outputed.

I would appreciate any help with this case.

Comment: Use COUNTIF or MATCH to match the first column records against the second.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are Column A & Column B, you can enter the following formula in Cell C1:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=0,A1,"")
```

The drag it to fill down and whatever doesn't appear in the second column will be listed in this column.

Comment: Do you know any workaround to get rid of the "blank" cells in column C? They are not exactly blank, there is just the formula without any visible output.
https://imgur.com/gUIAmvn

Comment: Errmm, you could paste them as values, then filter and remove them, it would really depend on what your goal is,... I would personally use macros to do most of the work for me...

Comment: Alright, pasting as values is sufficient. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

With the new Dynamic Array formulas(Currently only available to Office 365 Insiders) simply filter column A with countif:

```
=FILTER(A1:A4,COUNTIFS(B1:B4,A1:A4)=0)
```

Put that in the first cell and Excel will spill the rest down.

[image]

With Current versions we can use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$4)/(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$4,$A$1:$A$4)=0),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

But this requires that the formula be placed in the first cell and copied down till blanks appear.

[image]